# How to make child menu items appear on hover?

Tags: css, hover

I have an issue with this site made under Wolf CMS. 
I dont know what happened, but the menu child items are not
showing anymore!. Cant  understand why when I add CSS to allow
the display and style it, it doesn't work!
I dont see JavaScript code affecting it..maybe I'm missing something
can somebody advice??

http://goo.gl/PE238a

All the code via CSS i try to apply wont make any effect...

I cant figure out why my css wont render what I need to see...

```
#team-nav li {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  left: 1px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 1px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

I tried to position absolute and opacity 10 but wont work :(

At the wayback machine http://goo.gl/hYhuHB
i can see the working menu in a captured page of the site....
but there is so much addded code that I get confused..

Comment: There's a couple of Javascript errors on your page. Might be worth fixing those first to see if they're affecting the behavior of your page.

Comment: thanks jamie. I found using chrome the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; scripts.js:3` but cant understand much javascript can you help me understand if this is the problem? Maybe a selector is missing in the html... im desperate. in the internet archive I can find a working menu... http://goo.gl/hYhuHB but there is so much added code that I feel completely lost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following style to your `#nav`

```
#nav {
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
float: left;
margin: 0;
border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
width: 700px;
padding-top: 100px;
overflow: initial;<-- Added
}
```

Since your overflow is hidden and you `#nav` is `position:relative;` the `submenu` which overflows your `#nav` cannot be displayed. Try the above code that works like a charm. You can also add `overflow:visible;`

**NOTE**: Your `mobile.css` inherits the values of your `screen.css`. `#menu, #nav{overflow:hidden}` so your `screen.css` has to change with `#nav{overflow:visible}`